# Easy Trigger question

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I would imagine that this would be an easy question for someone who works a lot with T-SQL and especially Triggers:

I want to enforce the following constraints on all updates and inserts to this table:

1. If DiscountTypeId = 1, then FlatFee must not be NULL.
2. If DiscountTypeId = 2, then DiscountRate must not be null.

If either one of these two conditions fail on an insert or update to the table, I'd like to return an appropriate error.

The trigger appears not to do anything yet. .Can you provide the necessary changes so it performs as described?

```
USE [PandaVisa2008]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CustomerSpeed]    Script Date: 11/04/2010 15:51:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerSpeed](
 [CustomerSpeedId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [CustomerId] [int] NULL,
 [SpeedId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [DiscountTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [FlatFee] [money] NULL,
 [DiscountRate] [decimal](3, 3) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AgentFee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(USE [PandaVisa2008]

GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TRG_CustomerSpeed_OnInsertUpdate]    Script Date: 11/04/2010 15:38:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_CustomerSpeed_OnInsertUpdate]
ON [dbo].[CustomerSpeed]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @DiscountTypeId INT
        DECLARE @FlatFee MONEY
        DECLARE @DiscountRate DECIMAL(3, 3)

        SELECT
            @DiscountTypeId = DiscountTypeId,
            @FlatFee = FlatFee,
            @DiscountRate = DiscountRate
        FROM
            inserted

        IF @DiscountTypeId = 1
           AND @FlatFee IS NULL
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR (N'If @DiscountTypeId is 1, FlatFee must not be NULL',
                           10,
                           1)
            END

  IF @DiscountTypeId = 2
           AND @DiscountRate IS NULL
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR (N'If @DiscountTypeId is 2, @DiscountRate must not be NULL',
                           10,
                           1)
            END            
    END 

 [CustomerSpeedId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerSpeed]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_CustomerSpeed] CHECK  (([DiscountRate]>(0) AND [DiscountRate]<(1)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerSpeed] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_CustomerSpeed]
GO
```

### ***EDIT***

I got it to work. I haven't read up on Triggers to remedy my fundamental lack of understanding, but t his seemed to work, although I believe that the Check Constraint is the better approach:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_CustomerSpeed_OnInsertUpdate]
ON [dbo].[CustomerSpeed]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT
                       1
                   FROM
                       inserted I
                   WHERE  I.DiscountTypeId = 1
                      AND I.FlatFee IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

                RAISERROR (N'If DiscountTypeId is 1, FlatFee must not be NULL',
                           10,
                           1)
            END

       IF EXISTS (SELECT
                       1
                   FROM
                       inserted I
                   WHERE  I.DiscountTypeId = 2
                      AND I.DiscountRate IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

                RAISERROR (N'If DiscountTypeId is 2, DiscountRate must not be NULL',
                           10,
                           1)
            END            
    /*
     IF @DiscountTypeId = 2
        AND @DiscountRate IS NULL
         BEGIN
         Rollback Transaction
             RAISERROR (N'If @DiscountTypeId is 2, DiscountRate must not be NULL',
                        10,
                        1)
         END
    */
    END 

Your comments are welcomed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a CHECK constraint, not a triggers

```
ALTER TABLE Mytable WITH CHECK ADD
   CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_GoodName CHECK (
        NOT (DiscountTypeId = 1 AND Flatfee IS NULL)
        AND
        NOT (DiscountTypeId = 2 AND DiscountRate IS NULL)
)
```

Also, need to consider "if DiscountTypeId <> 1, does Flatfee have to be NULL" etc

Answer (score 2):

You fundamentally do not understand triggers. The very first thing you need to do is go read about triggers in Books Online with particular emphasis on learning about the inserted and deleted psuedotables. Next thing you need to know is a trigger should NEVER be written as if it will handle only one record at a time. Triggers operate on batches of records and trigger code must account for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe triggers can raise errors,  problem #1.

Comment: I see lots of examples of triggers that do raise errors here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Yes, can raise errors with RAISERROR. Better to use TRY/CATCH too: you may be thinking of pre-TRY/CATCH batch aborting behaviour

Comment: Do you see any errors if your run an insert from query analyzer vs running it from Visual Studio.    You do appear to be correct about being able to throw it,  but maybe trapping them is the issue.

Comment: I got the trigger to work. For some reason, I was getting a sytax error squiggly under the 3rd item in teh select list: @DiscountRate = DiscountRate. i disregarded it because, after triple checking it, I thought the variable name was correct. I stil believe it was. So I bounced Mgt Studio and pasted the same code into a new query window. This time, no squiggly error warning. I Altered the trigger, and it worked.

Comment: BTW, Unless I add a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION, the update still commits even though the error is thrown.

Comment: @VJK, your trigger still does not work if multiple records are inserted/updated. You truly, fundamentally, do not understand triggers and should not be writing them until you educate yourself or you will cause havok in your database.

Comment: It worked. I just tested it. I tried to update multiple records, setting the FlatFee column to NULL when the DiscountRateId was 1. The an  error was returned and no updates were performed. If The DiscountRateId was 2, I was able to update multiple rows to NULL. You're "RTFM" comments aren't helpful. If you have a specific criticicm, offfer a solution, otherwise, you may as well not reply.